# Creating a field in MsAccess

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have been working on this for some time now, and can't find the proper solution

I am creating a DB from the code:

```
OleDbConnection accessConnection = new  OleDbConnection(accessConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = accessConnection;
        //command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        accessConnection.Open();

       command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE " + table.TableName +  columnsCommandText;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And to make table this is the Create statement:

```
([LocationID] long,[Maincat] text,[Cat] text,[Subcat] text,[Soliciter] text,[Cost] decimal,[Money] text,[Unit] text,[Notes] text,[solution] text,[Reference] decimal,[Link] text,[LastUpdate] date,[Source] text,[Raw] text,[downstream] text,[workable] text,[trunvcet] text,[SourceDate] text,[Master] text,[Flag] long)
```

When the Table is created, all of the Text fields are made as Memo fields. I need Text fields

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
To set a field to Text, I needed to use this:

> TEXT(255)

Insted of Text